# MVVM - Auto Reset flag implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I have a boolean property in my custom control. I have a property changed callback method in which I'm resetting the flag value whenever the views update the property i.e., views will set the property value to true and in custom control I'm doing some processing and setting the property value back to false. When I update the property value in custom control to false it's not updated to the view side.

CustomControl:

```
public bool ResetFlag
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ResetFlagProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResetFlagProperty, value); }
    }
public static readonly DependencyProperty ResetFlagProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ResetFlag", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnResetFlagChanged));

private static void OnResetFlagChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var extendedTextBox= d as ExtendedTextBox;
    if (extendedTextBox== null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        //Do processing here
        extendedTextBox.ResetFlag = false;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:ExtendedTextBox ResetFlag="{Binding ResetValue,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="ResetFlag" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>

public bool ResetValue
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ResetValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ResetValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ResetValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ResetValue", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResetValue = true;
}
```

Can someone please help me in understanding why the value is not reflected in viewmodel when I set the boolean flag to false in custom control?

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, it's impossible to say for sure. But, WPF generally disables binding updates in one direction, when it is in the middle of processing an update in the other direction. It's not clear what led you to this design, but I doubt it's the best way to manage what you're trying to do. You should post a question that asks about that broader issue, instead of this specific implementation. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Just a sidenote: You do not need a `DependencyProperty` in the `ViewModel`, just a "normal" `Property`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your suggestion. I will update the question or I will create new question in different thread.

Comment: @FlatEric Yes I can use normal `CLR property` instead of `DependencyProperty`. But that doesn't solve the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @FlatEric is right: if it doesn't solve "*your problem*" it is because you are doing something else wrong (DataContext not set, VM not implementing correct methods etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Wy are you defining another `ResetValue` property in the `MainWindow` class? You should set the `ResetFlag` property of the `ExtendedTextBox` control.

Give the control an `x:Name` in your XAML markup:

```
<local:ExtendedTextBox x:Name="ctrl" ResetFlag="{Binding ResetValue,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

...and set the property of the control in your `Button_Click` event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ctrl.ResetValue = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm following MVVM approach (I know I have written the code in xaml.cs), hence the property is declared inside MainWindow class.

Comment: What? You have two properties but you set the wrong one. You should set the control's property and not the window's.